# Changing EQ settings in Logic Pro - Automation vs Separate Tracks

Tags: logic-pro, automation, eq

I have a software instrument track that requires two different EQ settings at two time spans in my project. Would it be better practice/wiser for me to create a duplicate track with different EQ settings and then duplicate the MIDI region? Or should I automate the EQ settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory the more track you have, the more CPU and memory you use so the more latency you get.

Different settings on the same track seems a wiser solution, but a bit more delicate to achieve.

The tricky part really appears when a software doesn't take in charge properly sudden changes on parameters, the dangers is getting glitches/noises or a too brutal changes in your mix.

- You can achieve this by using macros (it's even simpler in your case)
  with **param(s) A** on the minus position of the knob and **param(s) B** on the maximum position.
- You can also use [MIDI](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Instrument_Digital_Interface) to trigger different presets of your plugin (some plugins handle this kind of operation really nicely (like [FabFilter - Pro-Q](http://www.fabfilter.com/products/pro-q-2-equalizer-plug-in)).
- You can also (as you kind of mentionned it ..?) make some good old automation curves on your track.

**FYI**

> A macro is an adjustable value that can modulate another or other value(s) (sometimes in between a specific range).
>   You can find macros either in your DAW (well most of them) or in some plugins.
>   The possibility scope the macro object offers you, strongly depends on the tool(s) you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by macros? I've never heard the term used in the context of logic

Comment: I can't really help you with Logic, but I've added to my post a definition about macros.  Best :)

Comment: @sneelhorses One additional suggestion I would have is to set up two EQ plugins and automate the bypass feature of both instead of automating all of the parameters of the EQ (unless it's just one band).  I would also note that using two separate tracks may not be as bad as it is made out to be in this answer.  Yes, it will use additional processing power but unless you have a really old/poorly functioning machine, or are utilizing a very large amount of tracks, Logic's buffering should be able to handle everything just fine.  Latency should only really be an issue for overdubbing.

Comment: This is not untrue, but If options are made to do so lets use them. I was talking about the "best" so for me optimal solution. Arrangement can be really quickly overloaded, so the less tracks and plugins there is, the best it is. Do you want to write a separate answer or can I integrate your 2 plugins solution into my post ? Best :) .

Answer (score 1):

Better is pretty subjective :-) but I'd go with automation if the automation is simple. For something more complex I'd go with two tracks with the regions needed for each.